# In D7 how do I get JUST the value of a field in a view field template?

Tags: 7, views

This is at the top of the template file:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Default simple view template to all the fields as a row.
 *
 * - $view: The view in use.
 * - $fields: an array of $field objects. Each one contains:
 *   - $field->content: The output of the field.
 *   - $field->raw: The raw data for the field, if it exists. This is NOT output safe.
 *   - $field->class: The safe class id to use.
 *   - $field->handler: The Views field handler object controlling this field. Do not use
 *     var_export to dump this object, as it can't handle the recursion.
 *   - $field->inline: Whether or not the field should be inline.
 *   - $field->inline_html: either div or span based on the above flag.
 *   - $field->wrapper_prefix: A complete wrapper containing the inline_html to use.
 *   - $field->wrapper_suffix: The closing tag for the wrapper.
 *   - $field->separator: an optional separator that may appear before a field.
 *   - $field->label: The wrap label text to use.
 *   - $field->label_html: The full HTML of the label to use including
 *     configured element type.
 * - $row: The raw result object from the query, with all data it fetched.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
```

I was hoping "raw" was just the value in the field, but I think it's the entity id. PLEASE tell me there is a straight-forward way to get just the value of the field from this template!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to access the field's value with: $row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['value']

Comment: I don't like doing it this way, but it works, thank you.

Comment: @SomethingOn I agree with you wholeheartedly, you'd think there'd be a simple way to access these. I did a lot of research when I had this problem myself and that was the only way I could find to access the value. Subscribing in case someone else has better answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have devel installed then add `dpm($field);` to the template and see if the field array contains the value itself (if I remember right - it isn't). The second step (if the field array doesn't contain the value) will be to use `dpm($view);` ,and in the view array you have the value for sure (I think it is something like `$view->$row['field_name'][0]['value']` )

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to render the fields into views template using below code.

```
$fields['title']->content
```

In above code `title` is name of the field. You can get the field name for the view's fields as below:

- Go to Administration » Structure » Views
- Edit your views
- In the field section, click on last field in the views and check
  "Rewrite the output of this field" in the REWRITE RESULTS" section.
- In the "REPLACEMENT PATTERNS" section,  you will find the list of all
  fields which are placed before this field and this field also.

[image: Selecting fieldname for the views fields]

Comment: That still ends up giving me a <div> with the value...I just want the value. I find it incredibly silly that the value by itself isn't a variable option.