# How to get taxonomy term in Overwrite view exposed filters file?

Tags: nodes, views

views-exposed-form--CONTENT-NAME.tpl.php

Can we get content selected taxonomy term in this file

Comment: You need to provide more information about your views. Taxonomy term is fields or contextual filter or exposed filter for your views?

Comment: Jayendra Kainthola

Taxonomy term is field in view and we are searching content by exposed filters. so i am creating this file to change some layout filters, but I need to display taxonomy term name.

Comment: If Taxonomy Term is a field, then you are using wrong template file. You need to override views-view-fields.tpl.php for customization.

Comment: Please suggest me what templates we need to use

Comment: You need to override views-view-fields.tpl.php for customization. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85270/in-d7-how-do-i-get-just-the-value-of-a-field-in-a-view-field-template/85292#85292

Comment: Jayendra one more Question I am also change layout of filters so this file is work for that?

Comment: For the exposed form, you are overriding the correct template of the views. So, you need to override two template one for fields and another for exposed. For more information of views template, you can follow the link https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/group/views_templates/7

Answer (score 0):

Go to
Home » Administration » Structure » Views

Under the advanced tab at the right corner 
click on theme : Information 
There you can get a list containing file name for overriding templates.

From that you can create your file name accordingly

Comment: harshal file overwrite is working fine but i need to get taxonomy term, how to get taxonomy term in this file.